# Write WiFi ssid and password on NFC tag via ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, nfc, ionic-native, ndef

What I'm trying to do is to write a wifi network on an NFC tag that you have to bump your phone into a tag and that your phones connect to it. I tested this via NFC Tools and it worked.

- Tried to write it with my own NFC service method
  Didn't work because the type is text.

I'm trying to change the type of my NFC nDef write function but don't seem to find it in the documentation or online.

Typescript service NFC:

```
 WriteNFC(text: string) {
    this.writeNfcAlert(text).then(alert => alert.present());
    console.log(text);
    let message = [this.ndef.textRecord(text)];
    let listener = this.nfc
      .addNdefListener(
        listener => {
          this.ndefWrite = true;
        },
        err => {
          this.ndefWrite = false;
        }
      )
      .subscribe(event => {
        if (this.ndefWrite) {
          this.alertController.dismiss();
          this.nfc
            .write(message)
            .then(() => {
              this.alertController.dismiss();
              this.presentToast("Successfuly written to tag.");
            })
            .catch(() => {
              this.WriteNFC(text);
              this.presentToast("Not able to write to tag, try again.");
            });
        }
        this.alertController.dismiss();
        this.ndefWrite = false;
      });
  }

  WriteWiFiNFC(){
    this.writeNfcAlert("new WiFi connection").then(alert => alert.present());
    let message = [this.ndef.TNF_EXTERNAL_TYPE]
  }
```

I'm probably not exprienced enough with NFC. But I'm trying to find a solution on how to change the type of my NFC tag so that maybe when I scan a NFC tag for a contact it will detect it also like it does with NFC tools.

Thanks for the help in advance.

**Update:**
What I found out is that you have to use application/vnd.wfa.wsc

```
    let message = [this.ndef.record(this.ndef.TNF_MIME_MEDIA, "application/vnd.wfa.wsc", "", "Network Name: test Authentication Type:OPEN Encryption Type: NONE Pasword: kak")];
```

I'm still figuring out how to add the right payload, I'm gonna look through the documentation  https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Nfc/+/master/src/com/android/nfc/NfcWifiProtectedSetup.java.

**Update 2**
Found out there are a few specific variables you have to write on your NFC to let your phone recognize it as a network.
- NetworkName
- AuthenticationType
- EncryptionType
- NetworkKey
- MacAddress